# attach multiple database in sqlite - Node/express

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I have two SQlite databases.

1. Database1.db
2. Database2.db

How can I attach or use two databases together in SQlite, Node/express app.

To connect to Database1.db, I use following approach in Node/express,

db.js

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const fs = require('fs');
const dbFile = path.resolve(__dirname, "Database1.db");
const dbExists = fs.existsSync(dbFile);

if (!dbExists) {
  console.log("sqlite db file doesn't exist")
  fs.openSync(dbFile, 'w');
}

console.log("db file exists");

exports.database1 = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile, sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
  console.log(`Connected to disk database1.db`);
});
```

How to attach Database2.db ?